# TCL TK: Scroll on Top Window

Tags: window, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm to write an application which compares some sections of logs side by side by using nested text boxes in nested frames. these nested frames are overflowing the window size and I would like to contain and control with scroll. How can I do this?

-Syva

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the `scrollbar` command, which has a simple example of use near the end: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/scrollbar.htm#M34

If you are doing side-by-side comparison you may want to use a single scrollbar to control two text widgets.  You can find examples of how to do this at: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/multi+scrolling